How to test the **displayed** terminal output in golang (with escape sequences)
I wrote a golang library that displays multiple progress bars at once. To update each progress bar, I'm using some unix terminal escape sequences to move the cursor up and down and to clear and reposition the cursor. Is there a way to easily test the final output as how the terminal sees it?
The Examples from the testing library consider \033[2K\rHello (\033[2K clears the line and \r moves the cursor to the beginning of the line) and Hello different.
I have read a similar question: How to test a function's output (stdout/stderr) in unit tests. People there are suggesting to redirect stdout to a buffer, but my issue with that is that I would have to keep track of the cursor movements and line deletions.
To be more specific, in my program, an output like this in the terminal:
(9/10) ██████████████████  |
(12/20) ████████████        |

is a lot of escape sequences that moves the cursor around and clears the current line and redraws the intermediate progresses over and over. Is there a way for me to assert that a test suite outputs the snippet above as the snippet above, rather than the string with those escape sequences?

IMHO the formatting within the terminal is not your program's concern. Don't try to keep track of the cursor movements, or other escape characters and guess at what the terminal will do,  just check that the bytes you wrote are correct.

You can refer to this project github.com/redmask-hb/GoSimplePrint
demo:
package main

import (
    "time"
    "github.com/redmask-hb/GoSimplePrint/goPrint"
)

func main() {
    bar := goPrint.NewBar(20)
    bar.SetNotice("progress bar:")
    bar.SetGraph(">")
    for i := 1; i <= 20; i++ {
        bar.PrintBar(i)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
    bar.PrintEnd("Finish!")
}

